# vuejs radio button component

Tags: radio-button, vue.js, vue-component

I trying to make this custom radio button component to work in vuejs. How do I make the radio button checked with a value from parent component. I know you use v-model and set it to a same value in one of the input values, but it dont seem to get it work.

component:

```
export default Vue.component('radioButton', {
  template,
  props: ['name', 'label', 'id', 'value']
})
```

component template:

```
<label class="radio" :for="id">
  <input type="radio" :id="id" class="radio-button" :value="value" :name="name">
   <span class="radio-circle">
  </span>
  <span class="radio-circle__inner">
  </span>
  <span class="radio-button__label">{{ label }}</span>
</label>
```

html:

```
<radio-button name="options" id="option-1" label="1" :value="selectedValue" />
<radio-button name="options" id="option-2" label="2" :value="selectedValue" />
```

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle with what you've already done?

Answer (score 28):

For radio buttons, you need to pass true or false for the checked property to preset it to some state. Alternatively, your value in `v-model` should be equal to `value` of radio button so that it gets checked.

In the limited sample code you have posted, I believe your label is the button index like `1`, `2`, `3` and so on... And I think you want to select one of the buttons when the `selectedValue` matches `label` of that radio button. For example, if selectedValue is 2, then you want radio button 2 to be checked.

Assuming the above is correct, you need to make a one line change in your `radio-button` component template:

```html
<input type="radio" class="radio-button" :value="label" :name="name" v-model="value">
```

Note:

1. Your button `label` is the value for radio button. This is what you would expect to set to selectedValue when you click a particular radio button.
2. Your `value` in child component is actually `selectedValue` of parent component, which indicates the radio button that is currently chosen. So this should go into `v-model`

So, as per the docs on [Form Input Bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Radio), your radio button will get checked if the v-model variable is equal to the value of that radio button.

But now here is another problem: If you click on another radio button, you expect the `selectedValue` in parent component to change. That is not going to happen because `props` gives you one-way binding only.

To resolve this issue, you need to do a $emit from your child component (radio button) and capture it in the parent component (your form).

Here is a working jsFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/mani04/3uznmk72/

In this example, your form template defines radio-button components as follows:

```html
<radio-button name="options" label="1" :value="selectedValue" @change="changeValue"/>
<radio-button name="options" label="2" :value="selectedValue" @change="changeValue"/>
```

Whenever the value changes inside child component, it will pass a "change" event along with the label of radio button, which gets passed to `changeValue()` method of the parent form component. Once the parent component changes `selectedValue`, your radio buttons update automatically.

Hope it helps!

Comment: In order to reduce verbosity, since Vue.js `2.3.0`, you can use the `.sync` modifier on the parent side and emit the event with the pattern`update:propName`. Thus, defining `@change` is not required anymore. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally do it another way, to keep a v-model directive and avoid an @change event (which could be replaced by @input if any other logic has to be performed).  The thing here is that I the v-model value is equal to the "value" props in the radio-button component.

```
props: {
    value: {},
    v_value: {},
    ....
}
```

So all you have to do is pass the real current value to make some checks and $emit the value on click on a label, or on change on the input if you don't have any label.

```
<label :for="id" @click="$emit('input', v_value)">
      <input type="radio" :value="label" :name="name" :id="id" /> {{ label }}
</label>
```

I also added (but commented it) a version with simple html markup in case you want custom-looking radio buttons :

```
<div class="label" @click="$emit('input', v_value)">
      <span>{{ label }}</span>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Zyfraglover/ndcp8t6e/

Comment: This probably wouldn't work for keyboard based input and auxiliary devices.