# Vue.JS custom radio button component requires clicking twice

Tags: radio-button, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a custom radio button component with the following HTML markup:

```html
<div id="app">
{{message}} - {{sex}}
<radio value="m" v-model="sex" name="sex">Male</radio>
<radio value="f" v-model="sex" name="sex">Female</radio>
</div>
```

The component (and app) are defined as follows:

```js
Vue.component('radio', {
    model : {
      prop:'checked',
      event:'change'
    },
    props : {
      value:null,
      name:String
    },
  data : () => ({
    val:''
  }),
  methods : {
    update (e) {
        this.$emit('change',e.target.value);
    }
  },
  template:'<div><input :value="value" :name="name" type="radio" v-model="val" @change="update"><slot></slot></div>'
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'selected:',
    sex:''
  }
})
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6kvmLv6f/)

It switches the radio buttons correctly (for the most part).

**Problem**: in order to do so I have to click Male radio button twice. I'd like to be able to only click it once to toggle them. Perhaps I'm not using the `model` attribute described [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Customizing-Component-v-model) correctly?

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40474634/vuejs-radio-button-component) question, but it uses older Vue (which doesn't have `model` attribute) and I don't want to have to capture @change on the parent (the entire idea behind the separate component is to abstract as much logic as possible)

update: For anyone interested [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6kvmLv6f/1/) is the solution thanks to @thanksd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exactly sure what's causing that bug, but I see that you're doing some unnecessary data-binding that are apparently causing the issue.

1. Change the `radio` component template to this (don't need to pass a value or bind a v-model):

   `<div><input :name="name" type="radio" @change="update"><slot></slot></div>`
2. Get rid of the `val` data property (since it isn't being used now).
3. Change your update method to `this.$emit('change', this.value);` (you can just directly reference the value you've assigned this `radio` component).