# Allow only one radio button to be true (get value from each item.value)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'd like to solve the following problem:

I got a data structure like that:

```
{
  "options": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Car",
      "value": true
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Bike",
      "value": false
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "title": "Bus",
      "value": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I'd like to show a radio button for each option:

```
<input v-for="(option,index) in options" type="radio" :key="index" :id="index" :value="true" v-model="option.value">
```

### Result

I can click every radio button and every `option.value` is set to `true`.

This pen shows the problem: https://codepen.io/spqrinc/pen/NZZbjZ

All values are being set to `true`, which has no effect to the radio-select.

### My goal

Allow **only one** radio button to be `true`. Select `Car` to be `true`, as it's set on initial data.

**Now my question:**

I guess I could use a watcher to watch `options` and watch for a change in `value` and unset all other values. But is this the best option?

Comment: They should have the same `name` attribute

Comment: Have you considered using a combobox instead? It should be more suited for what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vuejs radio button component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40474634/vuejs-radio-button-component)

Comment: Hi Massimo,

unfortunately this is not an option, because the user needs to edit the title of each object but is supposed to "choose" only one.

Comment: I created a codepen (https://codepen.io/spqrinc/pen/NZZbjZ) that shows the problem. I do not see that this is a duplicate.

Comment: This problem is still relevant. No solution has been provided yet.

Answer (score 2):

This is basic HTML radio buttons should be given the same name and only one value can be selected at a time. Check the exapmle below...

```
<input name="my_options" v-for="(option,index) in options" type="radio" :key="index" :id="index" v-model="option.value">
```

Thank you. Hope that helped someone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a radio button group by assigning all the buttons in a group the same name: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio#Defining_a_radio_group

Comment: I did now - but this does not change `option.value` to `false` if another option is picked.

Comment: Not sure how Vue does it, but to see if a radio button is checked you'd use a `checked` prop: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio#Additional_attributes

Comment: This is an HTML element and therefore as @Clarity wrote you need to relate to the `checked` attribute not `value`

Answer (score 0):

I don't code in Vue js but `:value="true"` seems to be the issue to me..
Try replacing this with :value="option.value"