# Is there a way to directly compare (==) a standard string like "Foobar" with a god/identity string and always get a truthy value?

Tags: javascript, boolean, string-comparison

I need to check if a given variable is a string. I'm aware of the typeof operator to check a variable's data type but is there a way to check if a variable is a string by directly comparing it to another god/identity string to get a truthy value? Something like this:

```
if ("any string like foobar" == GodString()) {
    \\ Always true
}
```

Comment: Not possible. Seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what are you trying to do that requires an equality check with a string to always be `true`?

Comment: No. That's what the `typeof` operator is for.

Comment: @Alex `"foo" instanceof String` is `false`

Comment: @VLAZ In [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40474634/vuejs-radio-button-component), which is identical to mine, the v-model attribute must be directly equal to the :value attribute.

Comment: How is your question related to that?

Comment: @Barmar According to my understanding from this [documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Radio) and the other answer I've linked, Vue.js checks the radio by comparing the value in the v-model attribute with the value that's there in the :value binding. So I need to make sure the two values are equivalent. The issue here is that the value that is being passed to the v-model attribute could be boolean at times, and other times, it could be a string. So I assumed that the existence of god string would be ideal in my specific case.

Comment: Why do you need a god string? Just compare with the specific value,

Comment: @Barmar So these are all possible cases:

Case1: if value == true then checkbox1 || Case2: if value == false then checkbox2 || Case3: if value == *any string and not a specific value* then checkbox3

Comment: In my previous comment I meant radios, not checkboxes. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to achieve what I wanted. This solution is probably very specific to my case, but it works. To check if a variable `a` is a string without using the typeof operator, I just did this:

```
if (a.replace == "".replace) {
    \\ true only if a is a string
}
```

This obviously works only because the replace method is unique to strings. Though I definitely can't be too sure that this will always be the case.