# How to change the role in migration table either admin or user based on the selection in laravel-8?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-8

I developed one users table without role column , now i want to add role column in my migration table which contains either admin or user , if the registered person selects user radio btn in frontend UI page the role should be updated as user or if the person selects admin the role should be changed as admin in my migration table [in postman also how to pass role based on role the value should change in my database table] please help me to fix this issue

`UsersMigration table`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('fullName');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('mobile')->unique();
            $table->string('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->enum('role', ['user', 'admin'])->default('user'); //here 
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');

    }
}
```

`UserRegisterController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use JWTAuth;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    // AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login', 'register']]);
    }
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'fullName'=>'required|string|between:3,15',
            'email'=>'required|email|unique:users',
            'password'=>'required|regex:/^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{6,}$/',
            'mobile'=>'required|digits:10'
            ]);
        $user = new User([
            'fullName'=> $request->input('fullName'),
            'email'=> $request->input('email'),
            'password'=> bcrypt($request->input('password')),
            'mobile'=>$request->input('mobile')           
        ]);
        $user->save();
        return response()->json(['message'=>'Successfully Created user'],201);
    }
}
```

i am pasting my frontend UI page also which should be written in vue.js
`Register.vue`

```
<template>
<div class="main">
    <div v-if="flag==true" class="container">
        <img id="side-img" src="../assets/sideImg.png" alt="notFound" />
        <p id="side-content">Online Book Shopping</p>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="headings">
                <h5 class="signin" v-on:click="flip();" id="login" :class="{ active: isLogin }" @click="isLogin = true">Login</h5>
                <h5 class="signup" id="signup" :class="{ active: !isLogin }" @click="isLogin = false">signup</h5>
            </div>
            <form ref="myForm" @submit.prevent="handlesubmit">
                <div class="fullname">
                    <p>FullName</p>
                    <input type="name" id="name-input" class="namebox" required v-model="fullName" autocomplete="off" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3,12}">
                </div>
                <div class="username">
                    <p>EmailID</p>
                    <input type="email" id="Email-input" class="emailbox" autocomplete="off" required v-model="email" pattern="^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$">
                </div>
                <div class="password-section">
                    <p>Password</p>
                    <input :type="password_type" class="password" :class="{'password-visible': isPasswordVisible }" id="passField" v-model="password" pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{6,}$" required>
                    <i class="bi bi-eye-slash" id="togglePassword" @click="togglePassword();"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="mobile">
                    <p>MobileNumber</p>
                    <input type="tel" class="telephone" autocomplete="off" v-model="mobile" id="tel" pattern="^\d{10}$" required>
                </div>
                <div class="role-btns">
                    
                    <input type="radio" id="user" name="user" vlaue="user" >
                    <label for="user" class="radio-label">User</label>
                   
                    <input type="radio" id="admin" name="user" value="admin">
                    <label for="admin">Admin</label>
                </div>
                <button class="btn-section" id="btn" type="submit">Signup</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <Login v-if="flag==false" />
</div>
</template>

<script>

import service from '../service/User'
export default {
    name: 'Register',
    components: {
       Login: () => import('./Login.vue')
    },
    data() {
        return {
            fullName: '',
            email: '',
            password: '',
            mobile: '',
            password_type: "password",
            isLogin: false,
            isPasswordVisible: false,
            flag: true,
            title: 'Online Book Shopping'
        }
    },
    methods: {
        flip() {
            this.flag = !this.flag;
        },
        togglePassword() {
            this.password_type = this.password_type === 'password' ? 'text' : 'password'
            this.isPasswordVisible = !this.isPasswordVisible
        },
        handlesubmit() {
            let userData = {
                fullName: this.fullName,
                email: this.email,
                password: this.password,
                mobile: this.mobile
            }
            service.userRegister(userData).then(response => {
                if (response.status == 201) {
                    alert("user registered successfully");
                    this.$refs.myForm.reset();
                    this.$router.push('/login');
                }
                return response;
            }).catch(error => {
                alert("invalid credentials");
                return error;
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
    @import "@/styles/Register.scss";
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change radio name

```
   <div class="role-btns">
                    
                    <input type="radio" id="user" name="role" vlaue="user" >
                    <label for="user" class="radio-label">User</label>
                   
                    <input type="radio" id="admin" name="role" value="admin">
                    <label for="admin">Admin</label>
                </div>
```

and in controller

```
 $this->validate($request, [
            'fullName'=>'required|string|between:3,15',
            'email'=>'required|email|unique:users',
            'password'=>'required|regex:/^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{6,}$/',
            'mobile'=>'required|digits:10',
'role'=>'required|in:user,admin'
            ]);
        $user = new User([
            'fullName'=> $request->input('fullName'),
            'email'=> $request->input('email'),
            'password'=> bcrypt($request->input('password')),
            'mobile'=>$request->input('mobile') ,
            'role'=>$request->role ,
        ]);
        $user->save();
```

Comment: Thanks alot ,in frontend  how to write v-model for radio buttons @John Lobo

Comment: @Sravani check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40474634/vuejs-radio-button-component